# Using \setbeamercovered{transparent} on slide transition, tikz node texts fades, but paths disappear instead?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, animations, transparency

I want to have the paths appear on the slide along with the words when covered. Beamer seems not to do this. Is there a way to change this?

```
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}[h]

\begin{tikzpicture}[box/.style={draw,rectangle}]
\onslide<1>{
\node (Mary) at (0,0) {Mary};
}
\node<2> (Suzy) at (4,0) {Suzy};

\node (John) at (2,0) {John};

\path<1>  [draw, ->, line width=1pt, color=red] (Mary) edge (John);

\path<2>  [draw, ->, line width=1pt, color=red] (Suzy) edge (John);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Don't show only a snippet, make a complete example, that makes it much easier to test your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\begin{document}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}[h]

\begin{tikzpicture}[box/.style={draw,rectangle}]
\node[alt=<2>{opacity=0.2}] (Mary) at (0,0) {Mary};
\node[alt=<1>{opacity=0.2}] (Suzy) at (4,0) {Suzy};

\node (John) at (2,0) {John};

\path[draw, ->, line width=1pt, color=red,alt=<2>{opacity=0.2}] (Mary) edge (John);

\path[draw, ->, line width=1pt, color=red,alt=<1>{opacity=0.2}] (Suzy) edge (John);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This got most of what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @marmot's answer, I figure out that I could have both "covered" and "appearing" content, by combining my earlier version with his. This way, in the example below with three frames, I have the line for Suzy appear only after the line for Mary fades.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\begin{document}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}[h]

\begin{tikzpicture}[box/.style={draw,rectangle}]
\node (Mary) at (0,0) {Mary};
\node (Suzy) at (4,0) {Suzy};

\node (John) at (2,0) {John};

\path[draw, ->, line width=1pt, color=red,alt=<2-3>{opacity=0.2}] (Mary) edge (John);

\path[draw, ->, line width=1pt, color=red,]<3> (Suzy) edge (John);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```